# Ensuring years and months are running as part of data cleaning

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 datasets:

1. rainfall per month (mm) from 1982-01 to 2022-08
2. no. of rainy days per month per year from 1982-01 to 2022-08.

```
    month   no_of_rainy_days
0   1982-01 10
1   1982-02 5
2   1982-03 11
3   1982-04 14
4   1982-05 10
```

```
month   total_rainfall
0   1982-01 107.1
1   1982-02 27.8
2   1982-03 160.8
3   1982-04 157.0
4   1982-05 102.2
```

Qn 1: As part of ensuring data integrity, how do I ensure that the dates are running consecutively? i.e 1982-01 and next is 1982-02 and not a skip to 1982-03?

I am unsure how to perform the checking and have done a search online. Is it common practice to assume that the years and months are running?

Comment: What do you mean by "running"? At any case, I think you are looking for the ```pd.to_datetime``` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, separate the year from the month.

```
df.rename(columns={"month": "ym"}, inplace=True)
df[["year", "month"]] = df["ym"].astype(str).str.split("-", expand=True)
```

Then you can group the dataframe by year and count the number of observations per year (counts number of rows per year).

```
observations_per_year = df["year"]\
    .groupby(df["year"])\
    .agg("count")\
    .reset_index(name="observations")
observations_per_year[observations_per_year["observations"] < 12]
```

Assuming you have any years with less than 12 observations, they will be displayed like so:

```
    year  observations
0   1982            11
4   1986            11
5   1987            11
6   1988            10
11  1993            11
```

Given the lack of detail and no sample data provided, I made some assumptions about your data:

1. Each data set will not have more than one row for any month of the year (i.e., a maximum of 12 rows/observations per year).
2. Each dataframe contains a single observation per row, as shown in your examples (so you would do this for each dataframe prior to merging them). As such, counting rows per year-month is an accurate means of counting the number of observations for any given month.
3. The sorted order of the data is irrelevant (you can later sort by year-month if needed).